# Using Java ConstraintValidator without annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

Is there possibility to directly use specific implementations of ConstraintValidators without annotations? For example NotNullValidator without @NotNull annotation.

I'm writing a validation in which there are many field validations that depends on other fields, so I decided to write custom class level ConstraintValidator instead of creating many validation groups/sequences. But it would be nice if there is possibility to reuse other simple validations like NotNull, NotEmpty in my class level validator, so I don't have to manually add CosntrainViolations to ConstraintValidatorContext for specific fields.

I'm using Spring's @RestControllerAdvice to handle MethodArgumentNotValidException and ConstraintViolationException to map the errors to JSON response.